# Why Alamofire 4.4.0 turns JSON string with escaped JSON string (Swift 3)?

Tags: json, post, swift3, alamofire

I am having problem converting JSON data to string.

```
var url = "http://10.1.10.98/POSSytem/api/inventories/PutInventory?received={'id':'coke','price':4.99,'In_stock':2}"
print(url)
Alamofire.request(str, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: JSONEncoding, headers: nil)
        .response { (res) in
            print(res)
}
```

> LOGS:
>   original string -> http://10.1.10.98/POSSytem/api/inventories/PutInventory?received={'id':'coke','price':4.99,'In_stock':2}
>
> DefaultDataResponse(request: nil, response: nil, data: Optional(0
>   bytes), error:
>   Optional(Alamofire.AFError.invalidURL("http://10.1.10.98/POSSytem/api/inventories/PutInventory?received={\'id\':\'coke\',\'price\':4.99,\'In_stock\':2}")),
>   timeline: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 514563518.605, "Initial
>   Response Time": 514563518.597, "Request Completed Time":
>   514563518.597, "Serialization Completed Time": 514563518.605, "Latency": -0.007 secs, "Request Duration": -0.007 secs,
>   "Serialization Duration": 0.007 secs, "Total Duration": 0.000 secs },
>   _metrics: nil)

For some reason Alamofire turns url into different url. Adds escaped characters in JSON string. alamofire 4.4.0
It should have stayed :"http://10.1.10.98/POSSytem/api/inventories/PutInventory?received={'id':'coke','price':4.99,'In_stock':2}"

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let js = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) else {
           print("Error parsing json data \(dict)")
            return
        }

    let theJSONText = String(data: js,encoding: .ascii)


    url += "\(theJSONText!)"



    let finalURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)


    Alamofire.request(finalURL!, method: .post)
        .response { (res) in
            print(res)
    }
```

After using

> addingPercentEncoding

it encoded the JSON string for valid url and post call was triggered.